# Joomla 3: Customize the greeting text of login module

Tags: joomla

I would like to edit the joomla 3 log in greeting and I have no idea how to do that at the moment.

Greeting usually goes "Hi, username/name". I want it to go like "Hi, Mr username/name". I want the title of the user to preceed his or her name.

Now, I have already set up the database table for the title. I have already edited the joomla php and xml files to get these tables to show on my registration pages and user pages at the backend. So all that is left is calling the user's title to display before his/her name. Can anyone assist please?

Comment: For such Joomla related questions, it's best to use the [**JSE site**](http://joomla.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: No, really, don't edit the files. Override things, use plugins, etc, that is how Joomla is designed. You really should read the dev docs first ... there was no reason to add a table for this, you should have just used the profile table.

Comment: Wow. Okay. But I tried community builder, it just wasn't working out for me so I figured, hard core was the way to go.

Comment: I am not sure this info you gave me is adequate. I would like to pull the title from the data filled in by each user. The tile is a select field before the name. It has up to 6 options : ms, mr, pastor, .....etc.

Comment: Make a profile plugin to save the title and other information when registering. How many options you have in the field is completely irrelevant. Then copy the login module to a new module folder and change all the names to the new name.  In the helper change it so that it also queries the profile plugin and displays the title. Install the new module by the discovery method. Unpublish the old module, publish the new one.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But how do I make that plugin?

Comment: I'm sorry but Google is your friend for this, you need to go to the joomla documentation site and read the instructions.

Comment: Aight! Gracias. I will do that.

Answer (score 2):

You can go with a Language Override for the mod_login.

#### Steps:

1. In backend, go to: **Extensions -> Language Manager**
2. From the left sidebar, click on: **Overrides**
3. From the Toolbar (top) click the "**New**" button, to create new Language Override.
4. In next screen add the following:

   - **Language Constant**: MOD_LOGIN_HINAME
   - **Value**: Your desired salutation, e.g. `Hi Mr. %s,`.
     This will result to a greeting like: "Hi Mr username".

As a side note, I can't imagine what kind of changes you did on Joomla php and xml files and the database tables and how they could be related to changing the greeting text of the login module. Whatever the case, you want to make sure that you don't touch any Joomla core files and count the future of your site on such modifications.

Comment: Assuming it's an all male site. But from what he said he wants to get it from the database.

Comment: Yes, I want to get it from the database. All registered users on the site were made to fill a registration form. I had added title before name as a select field. After filling the form, the user registers and his title is saved into the database along with his other details. I want that title each user saved to appear before his or her name each time they log in.